# What is this type of style called?

Tags: terminology, trends

What is this type of style called?

[image]

Comment: You have your answer in the image title...it's a flat website design.

Answer (score 3):

As Alin accurately states in the comments, the title of the image gives away the style name - **flat design**, in this case used on a website design.

For more information, check out our tag for it: [flat-design](/questions/tagged/flat-design)

Comment: The tag has no wiki entry for it, so it doesn't explain just what is meant by that.

Comment: @JDługosz But it does lead to other questions about the topic