# Is there a name for this kind of graphic?

Tags: style-identification, flat-design

I found this image on Dribbble, but I see it's very different from normal images I see everyday. I don't think this is created from Photoshop; it's hard me to explain it. What is the name of this kind of graphics, and which software is used to create it?

[image]

Comment: Helly FastSnail and welcome! Please see our [style identification guidelines](http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/2929/23061) and edit your question to fit them

Comment: @ZachSaucier i think i have included all it says

Comment: It could use a descriptive title, what you've attempted already to try and identify the style you are interested in, and other examples so that we know precisely what style you're interested in. As is, you could be referring to several that are all used in the question

Comment: Also it would be good to explain why you don't think it is made in Photoshop.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the name of this flat illustration style?](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/50437/whats-the-name-of-this-flat-illustration-style) or [What is this type of style called?](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/58844/what-is-this-type-of-style-called)

Comment: That is **flat illustration/design** and any design program can do that. Depending on how skilled you are. Personally I would do it in Illustrator.

Comment: As already pointed out, it does indeed look like it was at one point a vector image, but since the image here has been rasterized and converted into jpeg format all the benefits of the vector format have been stripped from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a vector graphic and the style called Flat Design. You can create this kind images in Adobe Illustrator (in photoshop, too).

There is two kind of design trend in web. Realistic (skeumorphic) and Flat design. In realistic design there is too much gradients, shadows, highlights and it's looking realistic. In flat design you don't need too much shadow, gradients etc. You can check www.flatvsrealism.com to understand it well.

And also there is a trend by Google named Material Design. It's almost same thing with flat design but it has standards for motion, shadow and color palettes.

You can find much more when you google "Flat vs Realism" or check the links below:

http://blogs.adobe.com/dreamweaver/2015/05/flat-design-vs-material-design-what-makes-them-different.html

http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2013/12/infographic-flat-design-vs-skeuomorphism/

Comment: Can you edit your answer and tell me more about flat design?  I'll come back and upvote it.  (What qualities make it flat design, and maybe what are some other common elements of flat design?) -- I typed in "graphic style flat design" into google images, and it seems to match what you're implying.

Comment: I added some more details about it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a name for this style but it's a vector graphic.
To make your own in this style you're therefore best off using vector art tools.

I'd use Inkscape but most here will suggest Adobe Illustrator.