# What's the name of this drawing style

Tags: style-identification

I need to know the name of this drawing style, i found a lot of them on dribbble and everywhere. Is there is any tutorials on how to make them?

[image]
[image]

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/58844/23061

Comment: @ZachSaucier no its not the same thing

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Search it as "Flat illustration" or "Flat Landscapes" and here a few tutorials:

/*adobe illustrator*/

https://designmodo.com/flat-cityscape-illustrator/

https://youtu.be/h0iXsiw6zJI

https://youtu.be/Sk3IbXxBtE8

https://youtu.be/sr8eOeVWK1k

https://youtu.be/gXrOylKL4JE

Hope work for you!

Answer (score 3):

I don't think this style has a name that you could identify it in one word, but I think you could describe it as flat vector design - I'm guessing that the mountains in the background move in perspective to the foreground and character motion so there would be layers that you could move independently - so you would set up your artboard in Illustrator/Animate or which ever program you use. yaxpac in the post below has included some good tutorial reference.

Comment: I've  updated with more photoes

Answer (score 3):

It's called (Flat design/flat illustration/flat vector) 
it's made by adobe illustrator and it's main idea is usign simple non grdient color filled in a simple shapes with a simple typhography font
you can use it to make pandscapes low poly and icon (such as phone icons)        [image: Examples]

Answer (score 1):

These are simple vector designs. You can use any vector designing tool:

- CorelDraw
- Photoshop
- Illustrator
- Sketch App

Everyone knows that first three softwares can be used but the reason I've shared sketch app because it's **super user friendly** and recommended for UI designing. But you can also get great options for vector designing. Here is a quick demonstrations I've created in sketch using the image you shared.
[image]

To learn sketch these are the best tutorials available: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AV2OkzIGykA

Answer (score 0):

You should be looking into cell shading in order to learn more about this style of illustration.

Comment: you mean cel shading https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cel_shading

Answer (score 0):

Maybe polygonal illustration would be a close name. But this style hasn't an exact name.